Frontend Pod unable to Contact Backend pod using service name
I'm facing issue while setting up the K8-DNS from frontend to backend using nginx. In my frontend(react code) pod while using kubectl exec -it pod/<<frontend-pod>> -n app -- curl http://<service-name>:<port>/api/process?message=testevnewipw/ it's giving response, but if using localhost or using from web browser it's giving an error.
Below are the files:
deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1    
kind: Deployment    
metadata:    
name: frontend-deployment    
namespace: app    
spec:    
replicas: 2    
selector:    
    matchLabels:        
      app: frontend    
template:    
    metadata:        
      labels:        
        app: frontend        
    spec:        
      nodeSelector:        
        app: frontend        
      containers:        
      - name: frontend        
        image: frontend-image:latest        
        ports:        
        - containerPort: 80        
        command: \["/bin/sh"\]        
        args: \["-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"\]        
        env:        
        - name: BACKEND_HOST        
          value: "backend-service.app.svc.cluster.local"        
        - name: BACKEND_PORT        
          value: "5000"        
        volumeMounts:        
        - name: nginx-config        
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/frontend.conf        
          subPath: frontend.conf        
        resources:        
          requests:        
            cpu: "100m"        
            memory: "128Mi"        
          limits:        
            cpu: "200m"        
            memory: "256Mi"        
      volumes:        
      - name: nginx-config
        configMap:
          name: frontend-config
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: backend-deployment
namespace: app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:  
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:  
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        app: backend
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: backend-image:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000

service.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: frontend-service
namespace: app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP 
      port: 80 
      targetPort: 80
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: backend-service
namespace: app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000

configmap.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-config
  namespace: app
data:
  frontend.conf: |
    resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
        }

        location @backend {
            proxy_pass http://backend-service:5000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location ^~ /api/ {
            rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;  
            proxy_pass http://backend-service:5000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/;
            expires 30d;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }

and the nginx.conf as below:
resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://backend-service:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ^~ /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;  
        proxy_pass http://backend-service:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

Getting error while running from browser or pod using curl command:
2024/04/22 05:13:27 [error] 7#7: *71 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/process" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.224.0.4, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/process?message=Uchit HTTP/1.1", host: "4.157.106.175", referrer: "http://4.157.106.175/"
10.224.0.4 - - [22/Apr/2024:05:13:27 +0000] "GET /api/process?message=Uchit HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://4.157.106.175/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
2024/04/22 05:13:30 [error] 7#7: *71 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/process" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.224.0.4, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/process?message=Uchit HTTP/1.1", host: "4.157.106.175", referrer: "http://4.157.106.175/"
10.224.0.4 - - [22/Apr/2024:05:13:30 +0000] "GET /api/process?message=Uchit HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://4.157.106.175/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
^C
**kubectl exec -it pod/<<frontend-pod>> -n app -- curl http://localhost/api/process?message=testevnewipw/**
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.5</center>
</body>
</html>

But working fine If i curl using the service name:
kubectl exec -it pod/<<frontend-pod>> -n app -- curl http://backend-service.app.svc:5000/api/process?message=testevnewipw
{"response":"Processed: wpiwenvetset"}


Referring from this stack link try
updating the proxy_pass directives to use the DNS name of the backend service as
proxy_pass http://backend-service:5000.

"Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend is oriented towards a plain-Docker environment rather than Kubernetes, but its overall architectural points are still valid, and if you are using your own Nginx reverse proxy (rather than Kubernetes Ingress) then you should be able to adapt its setup.

What's the error you are seeing?

Hi @SaiChandraGadde, updated still getting same error(Updated the bode accordingly)

What's your ingress or gateway definition?
